# How to test that an error is raised in ligo?

Tags: error, ligo, testing

I would like to know if there is some way of testing for error raised with failwith in ligo using the testing framework?

There doesn’t seem to be any documented try-catch mechanism yet, or am I mistaken ?

Here is a simplified version of the code I want to test:

```
type identity_card = {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    validators: address set;
}

type t = (address, identity_card) map


let find (trombi:t) (user_address:address) = 
    match Map.find_opt user_address trombi with 
        Some card -> card
       |None  -> failwith("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have try..catch

I suggest that you look at the returned object of the transaction call, you have the information there

```
 const status =
    Test.transfer_to_contract(contrNFT, CreateNFTCardForMember(), 0 as mutez);
 const _ = Test.log(["status", status]);
```